# Prove $H_{\frac{1}{8}}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{\frac{1}{8}}-1}{x-1}dx$

Tags: definite-integrals, harmonic-numbers

I want to prove :

> $$H_{\frac{1}{8}}=8-\frac{\pi}{2}-4\ln\left(2\right)-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\pi+\ln\left(2+\sqrt{2}\right)-\ln\left(2-\sqrt{2}\right)\right)$$

Where $H_n$ is the n-th harmonic number.

Using the integral representation of harmonic numbers it follows:

$$H_{\frac{1}{8}}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{\frac{1}{8}}-1}{x-1}dx$$

Setting $x^{\frac{1}{8}}\ \mapsto u$ we have:
$$=8\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\left(u-1\right)u^{7}}{u^{8}-1}du=8\int_{0}^{1}\frac{u^{7}}{\sum_{i=0}^{7}u^{i}}dx$$

I know how to continue, but the way I use takes much time, so what would be the best way to prove the relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $t=x^{\frac{1}{8}}$

$$H_{\frac18}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{\frac{1}{8}}-1}{x-1}dx
=8\int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^8-t^7}{t^8-1}dt
=8-8\int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^7-1}{t^8-1}dt
$$

Decompose the integrand

$$\frac{t^7-1}{t^8-1} = \frac14\frac{1}{t+1}+\frac14\frac{t+1}{t^2+1}+\frac12\frac{t^3+1}{t^4+1}$$

and the integral

$$H_{\frac18}=8-2\ln 2 - 2I_1 - 4I_2\tag 1$$

where

$$I_1 = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{t+1}{t^2+1}dt
=\frac12\ln2+\frac\pi4\tag 2$$

$$I_2 = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{t^3+1}{t^4+1}dt=\frac14\ln2+\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{t^4+1}dt$$

Integrate

\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{1} \frac{2}{t^4+1}dt= \int_0^1\frac{1+x^2}{x^4+1} dx + \int_0^1\frac{1-x^2}{x^4+1} dx\\
=&\int_0^1\frac{d(x-\frac1{x})}{(x-\frac1{x})^2+2}  - \int_0^1\frac{d(x+\frac1{x})}{(x+\frac1{x})^2-2}
=\frac\pi{2\sqrt2}+\frac1{2\sqrt2}\ln\frac{\sqrt2+1}{\sqrt2-1}
\end{align}

Then

$$I_2 =\frac14\ln2+\frac\pi{4\sqrt2}+\frac1{4\sqrt2}\ln\frac{\sqrt2+1}{\sqrt2-1}\tag 3$$

Plug (2) and (3) into (1),
$$H_{\frac{1}{8}}=8-\frac{\pi}{2}-4\ln\left(2\right)-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\pi+\ln\left(2+\sqrt{2}\right)-\ln\left(2-\sqrt{2}\right)\right)$$

Comment: can you just tell me how letting $x-\frac{1}{x}=u$ and changing the lower limit for $x=0$ has been done? because when I want to substitute  $x-\frac{1}{x}$ I have a trouble with the lower limit since $x=0$ makes the fraction undefined.

Comment: @user715522 - $x- \frac1x \rightarrow -\infty$ as $x\rightarrow 0$. For instance, $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \tan^{-1} (x-\frac1x) = \tan^{-1} (-\infty) = -\frac\pi2$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a *non-elementary* approach to finding $H_{\frac{1}{8}}$ that makes use of the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function).

Making use of the result
$$\frac{H_n}{n} = - \int_0^1 x^{n - 1} \ln (1 - x) \, dx,$$
a result that can be analytically extended to all $n \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $n > -1$. Setting $n = 1/8$ one obtains
\begin{align}
H_{\frac{1}{8}} &= -\frac{1}{8} \int_0^1 x^{-\frac{7}{8}} \ln (1 - x) \, dx\\
&= \frac{1}{8} \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \int_0^1 x^{n - \frac{7}{8}} \, dx\\
&= \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(8n + 1)}\\
&= 8 \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \left (\frac{1}{8n} - \frac{1}{8n + 1} \right ).
\end{align}

From one of the [series representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Series_formula) for the digamma function, namely
$$\psi(z + 1) = - \gamma + \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \left (\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n + z} \right ),$$
where $\gamma$ denotes the *Euler–Mascheroni constant*, setting $z = 1/8$ we find
$$\psi \left (\frac{9}{8} \right ) = -\gamma + 8 \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \left (\frac{1}{8n} - \frac{1}{8n + 1} \right ).$$
Thus
$$H_{\frac{1}{8}} = \gamma + \psi \left (\frac{9}{8} \right ).$$
Now it is just a matter of finding the value for the digamma function.

It is known that for positive integers $r$ and $m$ ($r < m$), the digamma function may be expressed in terms of the Euler–Mascheroni constant and a finite number of elementary functions. Making use of the following [recurrence formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Recurrence_formula_and_characterization) for the digamma function, namely
$$\psi (x + 1) = \psi(x) + \frac{1}{x},$$
we see that
$$\psi \left (\frac{9}{8} \right ) = \psi \left (1 + \frac{1}{8} \right ) = \psi \left (\frac{1}{8} \right ) + 8.$$
The value for $\psi (1/8)$ can now be found from [Gauss' digamma theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Gauss's_digamma_theorem) which states that
$$\psi \left (\frac{r}{m} \right ) = -\gamma - \ln (2m) - \frac{\pi}{2} \cot \left (\frac{r\pi}{m} \right ) + 2 \sum_{n = 1}^{\lfloor \frac{m - 1}{2} \rfloor} \cos \left (\frac{2 \pi n r}{m} \right ) \ln \left (\sin \left (\frac{\pi n}{m} \right ) \right ).$$
Setting $r = 1, m = 8$ gives
\begin{align}
\psi \left (\frac{1}{8} \right ) &= -\gamma - \ln (16) - \frac{\pi}{2} \cot \left (\frac{\pi}{8} \right ) + 2 \sum_{n = 1}^3 \cos \left (\frac{\pi n}{4} \right ) \ln \left (\sin \left (\frac{\pi n}{8} \right ) \right )\\
&= -\gamma - 4 \ln 2 - \frac{\pi}{2} (1 + \sqrt{2}) - \sqrt{2} \ln (1 + \sqrt{2}).
\end{align}
So finally we arrive at the following value for $H_{\frac{1}{8}}$ of
$$H_{\frac{1}{8}} = 8 - 4 \ln 2 - \frac{\pi}{2}(1 + \sqrt{2}) - \sqrt{2} \ln (1 + \sqrt{2}).$$

Comment: Nice work and some useful tools. +1

Answer (score 0):

Using partial fraction decomposition
$$8\frac{\left(u-1\right)u^{7}}{u^{8}-1}=8-2\frac{u+1}{u^2+1}-4\frac{u^3+1}{u^4+1}-2\frac{1}{u+1}$$ seems to be workable.

Comment: thank you for this post, but is this the best (fastest) way for computing the integral?

Comment: @user715522. I think so. There only one term which is boring : $\frac 1{u^4+1}$